# Checking unconfirmed messages when a Reliable Proxy terminates

Tags: akka

In Akka, when a reliable proxy terminates, is it possible to determine which messages have not been confirmed to have reached the target?  What happens to unconfirmed messages when a reliable proxy terminates?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the current (2.2) version of `ReliableProxy`.  In Akka 2.3 I've [contributed](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0-RC1/contrib/reliable-proxy.html#Connecting_to_the_target) this feature and some other things (see the [`Unsent`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/#akka.contrib.pattern.ReliableProxy%24) class).

Comment: Updated to include Akka 2.3 info.